# How to extract the full url (subdomain,domain and directories) with ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a way, using the functionality in ZF, to get the full url
(http[s]::/xxx.yyyy.ddd/ggg/hhh)

I am currently in?
baseUrl() will only give me the path, not the domain and sub domain.

I know how to extract it from the $_SERVER, trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use getRequest() method of your controller to get an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Http object. then try the getHttpHost() method of the request object. so in your controller, it would be like this:

```
$hostName = $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost();
```

Construct your full URL like the following:

```
$this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Comment: Funny, as time went by I learned that ZF is a nicely written OO FrameWork, but you have to write alot to achieve simple things. Today I use the library where I can achieve what I want with most minimal writing.